Dynamically calculate a set of critical values for Johansen cointegration test
The formula to calculate either trace statistics or max eigenvalue in Johansen test involves multiplying eigenvalues by number of observations (T).

It means that if the number of observations is big enough, e.g. 1K, 10K, 100K, trace statistics will likely to exceed critical value. This will mistakenly find cointegration where it doesn't exist.
Is there a way to tune up the formula for trace statistics or critical values or apply additional matrix trasformation on top of EVD to better match eigenvalues and critical values?
